# Flutter Firestore Save time in UTC

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a timestamp problem here is datetime picker

```
                  DatePicker.showDateTimePicker(context,
                      showTitleActions: true,
                      currentTime: widget.eventDateStart,
                      minTime: DateTime(2019, 5, 5, 20, 50),
                      maxTime: DateTime(2100, 6, 7, 05, 09),
                      locale: LocaleType.fr, onConfirm: (date) {
                    widget.eventDateStart = date;
                    setState(() {
                      print(widget.eventDateStart); // I/flutter (13213): 2020-10-10 11:00:00.000Z
                    });
                  });
```

When i save into firestore i do this:

```
        print(widget.eventDateStart); // 2020-10-10 11:00:00.000Z  (GOOD)
        print(widget.eventDateFinish); // 2020-10-10 11:00:00.000Z (GOOD)
        print(DateTime.now()); //2020-10-10 15:57:21.873998
        //Add the event.
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('nurseries')
            .doc(widget.favoriteNurseryId)
            .collection('events')
            .add({
          'eventName': _eventName,
          'eventDescription': _eventDescription,
          'eventDateStart': widget.eventDateStart,
          'eventDateFinish': widget.eventDateFinish,
          'eventPrice': _eventPrice,
          'eventKidsPayed': FieldValue.arrayUnion([]),
          'eventIsPrivate': false,
          'createdDate': DateTime.now(),
        });
```

Then it save in firestore like this

eventDateStart = October 10, 2020 at 7:00:00 AM UTC-4
eventDateFinish = October 10, 2020 at 7:00:00 AM UTC-4

So when i show dateStart and dateFinish of an event I always have the wrong time in my application.

**So my question is:**
How to Solve ?
Why it convert in UTC-4 when saving :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was when i was initiating the value of the datetime picker it was in UTC time. Sorry all, it was more a problem on my side.